# Fix "there was an error opening the windows firewall with advanced security snap-in"

Tags: windows-7, firewall

I had this error when opening windows firewall with advanced security:

```
There was an error opening the windows firewall with advanced security snap-in. 
Error code: 0x6D9
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft automatic diagnoser and fixer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/17613/automatically-diagnose-and-fix-problems-with-windows-firewall) fixed it (seemed to be some kind of printer conflict in my case):

In case the link breaks, the following might be good search terms:

```
Microsoft Automatically diagnose and fix problems with Windows Firewall
```

Comment: @SkyRamon Fair enough & understand. In my case the search terms (firewall, snap-in, 0x6D9 etc) did not give an answer - hence even a downvoted answer such as this would have saved me time.